# Overriding device scope in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How is device scope handled in the following situation, where an outer device scope is overridden by an inner device scope:

```py
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    a = function1()

    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        b = function2()

    with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
        c = function3()

    d = a+b+c
```

My intuition is as follows:

1) "a" is computed first on "cpu:0"

2) "b" and "c" and computed in parallel on "gpu:0" and "gpu:1", respectively.

3) "d" waits for "b" and "c" because it depends on them, and when their values become available, "d" gets computed on "cpu:0"

Is my intuition correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly, with a few subtle points:

(a)  "b" and "c" *could* be computed in parallel, provided there are no control flow dependencies or data dependencies in what they're doing.  But whether they actually *are* executed truly at the same time is unpredictable from this example.  (I assume that was already obvious, but I wanted to be sure it was to others who might read this later.)

Note also that as specified, `b` and `c` don't explicitly depend on `a`, so it's possible that all three of them could be executed concurrently.  It is not the case that `a` *must* be executed first.

(b)  By default, if you don't supply any configuration options, device placement is "soft" -- the runtime can override things if the op can't be executed on the specific device.  For example, a CPU-only op could be moved from a GPU back to `/cpu:0`;  or an op pinned to `/gpu:1` could be moved to `/gpu:0` if the graph was run on a machine that had only a single GPU.

You can control the hard-vs-soft placement by supplying a configuration to the `tf.Session`:

```
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)):
```

Comment: @dga Device placement seems to be "hard" by default, not "soft". I use TF 0.10.0rc1 and the following code outputs "False": print(tf.ConfigProto().allow_soft_placement)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

PS, to check your intution, you could do something like this

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name="a")
  with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    b = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name="b")
    with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
      c = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name="c")
      d = a+b+c

print d.graph.as_graph_def()
```

This gives the underlying graph definition that TensorFlow system will run

Comment: Actually that graph def won't reflect potential device reassignment that happens with "soft_placement" as dga pointed out, that happens later